# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity Unable to cast object of type 'GroupPrincipal' to type 'UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal, principalcontext, groupprincipal

Good morning,

i'm trying to find a user in our active directory, but am getting the following exception:

```
 {System.SystemException} = {"Unable to cast object of type  'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type
 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'."}
```

my code is as follows, and it seems to have worked in the past, not sure what has changed. i've been staring and debuging and can't find the issue, please help.

```
 using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(
                ContextType.Domain, host, uContext))
            {

                if (ctx != null)
                {

                    using(UserPrincipal p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,IdentityType.SamAccountName, username))
                    {
```

where uContext is: `"CN=Users,DC=my,DC=eh,DC=tech,DC=com"`
and host is: `my.eh.tech.com` and the username is:madamzuzu

when i look for the user in the AD, they are shown correctly with the following `DN:CN=madamzuzu;CN=Users,DC=my,DC=eh,DC=tech,DC=com`

i can't understand where the "groupprincipal" is coming from?

Comment: Just a stupid question - are you sure that `CN=madamzuzu;CN=Users,DC=my,DC=eh,DC=tech,DC=com` points to a user and not just a container? What happens if you use `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity` instead?

Comment: Check your input parameters ?

Comment: which input parameters? i've debugged it and went through every single variable. all looks ok :(